# ReDim Preserve from 1-dimensional to 2-dimensional

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a one-dimensional array:

```
Dim array1() As Variant
array1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
```

conceptually looking like this:

```
A
B
C
D
```

I would like to add a second dimension to this array, keeping the original data.  I want to add two "columns" to this array to store data.

```
Dim lngArrayLength as Long
lngArrayLength = UBound(array1, 1)

' Zero-indexed, so now should have 3 columns
ReDim Preserve array1(lngArrayLength, 2)
```

Resulting in this:

```
A    NULL    NULL
B    NULL    NULL
C    NULL    NULL
D    NULL    NULL
```

Problem is that my ReDim Preserve command throws a Run-time error: '9': Subscript out of range error. I can't figure out why.

Comment: You cannot change the number of dimensions with `Redim Preserve` nor can you change the number of elements of anything but the last dimension.  You need to create a new array of the required size and copy the data from the old array yourself.  See [Functions For VBA Arrays](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm) for lots of ideas.

Comment: @TonyDallimore - Well, that's the answer... I don't think I can tag a comment as an answer, but that's it...  Thanks!

Comment: @TonyDallimore Really? That's very disappointing. The fact that `ReDim Preserve` cannot accomplish this is common knowledge and not interesting. I suspect that is why it was not offered as an answer. The  only solution that is commonly known is what Demetri offered. I tried to offer something new and interesting to accomplish your objective... redimming a 1D array to 2D and keeping the data.

Comment: @ExcelHero - It sure wasn't common knowledge to me, and couldn't find that explicitly stated anywhere else.  Your solution is pretty slick, I just can't seem to figure out how to use it in my extended scenario.  I see how it works in the small example set here, but on the actual/larger situation, I'm not sure I grasp how it would come together.  Thanks for helping though... I will keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: fwiw, the "preserve" keyword does **not** preserve the existing array. It's shorthand to allocate a new array and copy each element to the correct location in the new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is sort of a cheesy solution:

```
Dim Array1() As Variant, TempArray() As Variant

Array1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
ReDim TempArray(0 To UBound(Array1), 0 To 2)

For i = 0 To UBound(Array1)
    TempArray(i, 0) = Array1(i)
Next i
Array1 = TempArray
```

Comment: This is what I ultimately used.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`ReDim` is not capable of re-sizing an array to a larger rank (number of dimensions).

The common way to approach this is to create a new array of the rank you wish and to loop through all of the elements of the original array, assigning them one-by-one to the new array.

Here is an interesting alternative that is not widely know that can accomplish the same thing with no VBA looping of elements:

```
array1D = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")

array2D = Evaluate("{""" & Join(array1D, """;""") & """}&{"""","""",""""}")
```

Outcome: 1D array will be transformed to 2 dimensions (3 columns wide, source in 1st column).

Outcome: the two new columns will hold exactly the same data as the first column, but of course you are now free to assign whatever new values you want to the new columns.

Caveat: each dimension's lower bound will be 1.

Caveat: this is for arrays of text. A similar method can be used for numeric arrays.

Caveat: original array elements cannot contain any semicolons.

The biggest caveat with the above method is that the maximum length of the string that VBA's Evaluate() function can process is just 255 characters. To bypass that limitation, we use a function call during the evaluation, like so:

```
Private array1D

Public Sub Array1dTo2d()

    array1D = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")

    array2D = [transpose(Arr())&{"","",""}]

End Sub

Private Function Arr()
    Arr = array1D
End Function
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a dynamic way to implement this method so that it is easy to specify the number of columns in the resultant 2D array.

Just run the TestArrayConversions() routine to see three different examples:

```
Private array_

Public Sub TestArrayConversions()

    array1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")
    array1 = Array1dTo2d(array1, 3)
    MsgBox "2D array has:" & vbLf & UBound(array1, 1) & " rows" & vbLf & UBound(array1, 2) & " columns"

    array1 = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
    array1 = Array1dTo2d(array1, 25)
    MsgBox "2D array has:" & vbLf & UBound(array1, 1) & " rows" & vbLf & UBound(array1, 2) & " columns"

    array1 = Array("we", "can", "do", "it")
    array1 = Array1dTo2d(array1, 6)
    MsgBox "2D array has:" & vbLf & UBound(array1, 1) & " rows" & vbLf & UBound(array1, 2) & " columns"

End Sub

Public Function Array1dTo2d(arr1D, columns)
    array_ = arr1D
    Array1dTo2d = Evaluate("transpose(Arr())&{" & Application.Rept(""""",", columns - 1) & """""}")
End Function

Private Function Arr()
    Arr = array_
End Function
```

Comment: this also works ok for small example files like this, but how would you even handle this for an array that was of variable size?

Comment: Ahh. Well in to do that you just change this:  `{"","",""}` which as it stands now is for THREE columns.

Comment: Right, but if I'm writing a function that sometimes adds 3 columns, sometimes 10, sometimes 100... It gets cumbersome unless I'm missing something about how this works.

Comment: Hold on. I'll give you a dynamic solution using this.

Comment: @gotmike Please see update at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the `Private array_` line do?

Comment: @gotmike It just defines a variable with module-level scope. I called it `array_`

Comment: Good old Google search and found this. 5 years on and this is still helpful!

Comment: @alowflyingpig I'm glad my answer helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Demetri's answer is not cheesy at all.  Here is the same code but instead of putting the elements into a 2d column, puts them into the first row of the same named 2d array.  Thanks!

```
Dim Array1() As Variant, TempArray() As Variant 

ReDim tempArray(0, UBound(Array1))
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(Array1)
    tempArray(0, i) = Array1(i)
Next i
Array1 = tempArray
```